# Screenshot > Text (OCR) > Key information

Tags: machine-learning, text, computer-vision, ocr

I'm using Googles Vision API to analyze screenshots of error messages from a product of ours. The OCR part is easy with these managed services, but is there any best practices tools to use on the acual text?

More specifically an error screenshot will contain things like product name, product version, version of underlying operating system, if OS is 32 or 64 bit and the actual error message (C# Stacktrace)

So all the text is there from the OCR Scan but since screenshots are taken by user one cannot assume the different info above is in specific areas of the screenshot.

How to go about analyzing this data? Are we talking simple string manipulation and custom domain knowledge (Tried this and it get me pretty far), or is this the job of some sort of machine learning text analysis offered by google/microsoft (or is that overkill)?

Comment: I don't think that Machine Learning is necessarily overkill, it depends how many different patterns you are dealing with - you can OCR the image to generate a text data set and train models that will help you categorize the errors without needing a bunch of regex or rules written in code.  The question is whether or not you want to go through that work.  Just remember you need to have the training data up front and likely you will need to keep training models as you go to keep them accurate.

Answer (score 0):

> So all the text is there from the OCR Scan but since screenshots are taken by user one cannot assume the different info above is in specific areas of the screenshot.

1. Using simple [Template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) find *error message window* you are looking for in screenshot.
2. Use Googles Vision API in specific areas relative to position you find in step 1, to obtain specific informations.